# Override MavenSimpleLogger in Custom Maven Plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I'm writing a maven plugin and a dependency makes a cast like so:

```
ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger logger = 
      (ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger)LoggerFactory.getLogger("ROOT");
```

which fails with this error:

```
org.slf4j.impl.MavenSimpleLogger cannot be cast to ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger
```

I've tried adding direct dependencies to logback and moving dependencies around in my pom but I can't figure it out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should contact the maintainers of that dependency. They should not assume to know the implementation provided by the `LoggerFactory`.
For Maven it was required to create our own implementation in order to adjust the behavior based on Mavens specific logging arguments like `-X / --debug`

Comment: Thanks for the response! The problem actually lies in the source code for [Apache Qpid](https://qpid.apache.org/index.html) and it looks like they've made a ton of changes between versions 6.x and 7.x but I don't see any information regarding a release date for 7. I realize I may be SOL but I was hoping someone had some magic for me.

Comment: Accepting your answer as it was an issue on their end and it's fixed in new versions. Thanks!

Comment: Magic can only be done by manipulating the bytecode. And that's probably possible. Have a look at the maven-shade-plugins relocate option. It explains relocating packages, but I think it is also possible to relocate pattern `ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger` to shadePattern `org.slf4j.impl.MavenSimpleLogger` (explicit classes instead of packages, worth trying). The only problem I can imagine is that the `MavenSimpleLogger` will be part of the jar, so I'm not sure of the correct instance will be picked up from the classloader.

Comment: I just ended up using the example code they posted in that issue! Thanks for the suggestion though!